# Vim: Changing the visual mode cursor when using a terminal

Tags: vim, terminal

I'm using vim in a terminal.  When I go to visual mode, my cursor is a blinking vertical bar and it doesn't highlight the last character I'm on.  This makes me miss or overshoot the visual block I'm trying to edit.  I'd like the cursor itself to have the same shape as the visual block.  How do I do that?

I'm in the terminal which is important.  Here's what changes the cursor in normal and insert mode, respectively:

```
if &term =~ "xterm\\|rxvt"
  let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[4 q"
  let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[2 q"
  " 1 or 0 -> blinking block
  " 2 -> solid underscore
  " 3 -> blinking underscore
  " Recent versions of xterm (282 or above) also support
  " 4 -> solid block
  " 5 -> blinking vertical bar
  " 6 -> solid vertical bar
endif
```

I can't find a variable for visual mode cursor, though.

Comment: There is none (and no apparent way to do this without modifying vim).

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: @AndrewHaust windows 10 using vim through cygwin

Comment: @DanielKaplan ah, sorry, I'm of little help there.  There is a solution for mac that accomplishes what you are talking about (possibly mixed with my own custom colour settings?  I never know what affects what) but I've never used cygwin before.  https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim is the plugin which may be useful as a starting point?  Sorry I can't be more helpful.